# LINQ to SQL can't cast Int32 to String - how is that possible?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm getting this error

```
  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
```

when doing a routine LINQ to SQL query:

```
  Return (
       From n In DbContext.Newsletters 
       Where n.NewsletterID = NewsletterID
     ).FirstOrDefault
```

Here's the stack trace FWIW.

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.]
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +1151
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +113
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +344
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +56
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +265
   ...
```

Two questions:

1. How is it possible that an Int32 can't be cast to String?
2. How can I debug something this? Since it all happens deep in the bowels of LINQ, I can't even get any indication what field this is angry about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly your entity mapping is incorrectly mapping an int to a string somewhere?  Check the mapping for every property of Newsletters.

Answer (score 0):

one of the 2:
either

```
    Return ( 
   From n In DbContext.Newsletters  
   Where n.NewsletterID = NewsletterID.ToString() 
 ).FirstOrDefault
```

or

```
   Return ( 
   From n In DbContext.Newsletters  
   Where n.NewsletterID.ToString() = NewsletterID 
 ).FirstOrDefault
```

BC those are mostlikely different types

Comment: No, n.NewsletterID and NewsletterID are both Integers. I get the error in the debugger just by asking to see DbContext.Newsletters.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't cast a int to a string because the types are incompatible, but you can convert it.  I suspect it's as simple as:

```
Return ( 
       From n In DbContext.Newsletters  
       Where n.NewsletterID = int.Parse( NewsletterID )
     ).FirstOrDefault
```

Because the local variable is a string and the database column is an integer.

Comment: No, n.NewsletterID and NewsletterID are both Integers. I get the error in the debugger just by asking to see DbContext.Newsletters.

Comment: @Herb - Perhaps you have an error in your LINQ mappings? Have you by chance changed the type of some column after you added it using the designer without updating the designer's understanding of it?

Answer (score 0):

`Int32` can't be cast to a `String` since they aren't at all the same type.  You can convert an `Int32` to a `String` via `ToString`, but there isn't a cast available.

From that simple statement, I would have to guess that `n.NewsletterID` and `NewsletterID` are not the same type.  One needs to be converted to an `Int32` or a `String`, e.g.

```
  Return (
       From n In DbContext.Newsletters 
       Where n.NewsletterID = NewsletterID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
     ).FirstOrDefault
```

or, more likely

```
  Return (
       From n In DbContext.Newsletters 
       Where n.NewsletterID = Integer.Parse(NewsletterID, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
     ).FirstOrDefault
```

depending on which type is on each side of the expression.

Comment: No, n.NewsletterID and NewsletterID are both Integers. I get the error in the debugger just by asking to see DbContext.Newsletters.